# Node.js/Express.js/consign(): default request works ("/") but ("/tasks") returns a 502:Bad Gateway

Tags: node.js, express

while the code is able to request successfully an app.get ("/")however, when I tried to request an app.get("/tasks"), it fails and instead returns a 502:Bad Gateway. I've checked the yarn logs and there is no error showing.  below are my code artifacts and live code. 
**live code:**
[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lab0-apipilot-t4fmo)

**Project Folder structure:**
[image]

**src > models > tasks.js file:**
[image]

**src > routes > tasks.js**
[image]

**src > index.js:**
[image]

when i go to  request /tasks
[image]

it returns a 502: Bad Gateway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
consign({ cwd: "src" })
  .include("./models")
  .then("./libs")
  .then("./routes")
  .into(app);
```